# Variable Indefinida $_POST

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy intentando hacer que al dar clic en un checkbox quede el tilde marcado (actualizando la web). Alguien me ayudo a armar el código de JS, ya que soy nuevo con JS. y funciona perfecto, Pero a la hora de hacer el update en la BD, me dice que la variable esta indefinida, y no se porque. Muestro el código:

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".habilitar").forEach((fila) => {
fila.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const tr = fila.parentNode.parentNode;
  const id = tr.children[0].children[0].value;
  const formdata = new FormData();
  if (e.target.checked) {
    let habilitar = true;
    formdata.append("ID", id);
    formdata.append("habilitar", habilitar);
    console.log(habilitar);
    console.log(`El id es ${id}`);
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/Gestion_de_Comedores/Comedores_Totales/TEST/archivo.php", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formdata,
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Enviado correctamente");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  } else {
    let habilitar = false;
    formdata.append("ID", id);
    formdata.append("habilitar", habilitar);
    console.log(habilitar);
    console.log(`El id es ${id}`);
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/Gestion_de_Comedores/Comedores_Totales/TEST/archivo.php", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formdata,
    })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Enviado correctamente");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }
});
});
```

Los input (checkbox):

```
                <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="id-datos" value="<?php echo $row[6] ?>">
            <?php if ($row[7] == true): ?>
            <input class="habilitar task-chk" type="checkbox" checked >
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php if($row[7] == false): ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="habilitar task-chk" >
            <?php endif;?>
            </td>
```

Y el archivo que recibe el evento, el cual según el estado del checkbox haría el update en la BD:

```
<?php

include('Conexion\conexion.php');

$is_check = $_POST['habilitar'];
$id = $_POST['ID'];

$query = "UPDATE factlog_comedor set is_check = '$is_check' WHERE ID = '$id'";
mysqli_query($con, $query);

?>
```

Le he buscado mil vueltas, pero no logro encontrar la solución, en la consola al hacer clic en el check, me muestra los datos enviados, y esta perfecto, pero me falta este tema. Si pudiera pedir una ayuda, os agradeceré mucho!

**EDIT:** Estuve leyendo, y probé de esta forma:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/Gestion_de_Comedores/Comedores_Totales/TEST/archivo.php", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({formdata: formdata})
})
```

y recibirlo asi en el PHP (archivo.php):

```
$datos = json_decode($_POST['formdata'], true);
```

pero aun así, en la consola, me muestra los datos obtenidos correctamente, y que se envía al PHP, pero en el `archivo.php` me dice que la variable esta indefinida, sigo probando y esperando sus comentarios.

**EDIT:**

> array(41) { ["MIBDIRS"]=> string(24) "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs" ["MYSQL_HOME"]=> string(16) "\xampp\mysql\bin" ["OPENSSL_CONF"]=> string(31) "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf" ["PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["PHPRC"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["TMP"]=> string(10) "\xampp\tmp" ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(15) "localhost:8080" ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" ["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]=> string(1) "1" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(129) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/108.0.1462.54" ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(124) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(13) "gzip, deflate" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(47) "es,es-ES;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6" ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=> string(45) "lang=en; PHPSESSID=rioj5apthouvk6th1r0irevop2" ["PATH"]=> string(1073) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenel;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenel Shared\LNVSuite Client Components\7.5;C:\IBM\ITM\InstallITM;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\IBM\ITM\bin;C:\IBM\ITM\TMAITM6;C:\Program Files (x86)\Acuant\SDK;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files (x86)\OnGuard;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenel;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps" ["SystemRoot"]=> string(10) "C:\Windows" ["COMSPEC"]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" ["PATHEXT"]=> string(53) ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC" ["WINDIR"]=> string(10) "C:\Windows" ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(98) " Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.1.10 Server at localhost Port 8080 " ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(47) "Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.1.10" ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(10) "localhost" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(10) "localhost" ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(4) "8080" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(13) "10.111.212.91" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs" ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=> string(4) "http" ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=> string(0) "" ["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs" ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(20) "postmaster@localhost" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(71) "C:/xampp/htdocs/Gestion_de_Comedores/Comedores_Totales/TEST/archivo.php" ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "58664" ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(56) "/Gestion_de_Comedores/Comedores_Totales/TEST/archivo.php" ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(56) "/Gestion_de_Comedores/Comedores_Totales/TEST/archivo.php" ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(56) "/Gestion_de_Comedores/Comedores_Totales/TEST/archivo.php" ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=> float(1672057184.084342) ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1672057184) }

Cambié la IP por localhost.

Comment: Cual es el error? que dice "exactamente"?

Comment: Hola, Undefined variable $is_check in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestion_de_Comedores\Comedores_Totales\TEST\archivo.php on line 12

Comment: Undefined variable $id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestion_de_Comedores\Comedores_Totales\TEST\archivo.php on line 12

Comment: Y que existe en ese archivo? Porque el codigo que pegaste arriba ni siquiera tiene linea 12... Es otro archivo distinto? Puedes compartir el código completo de archivo.php?

Comment: Si, no me di cuenta, la estaba editando probando...  Warning: Undefined array key "habilitar" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestion_de_Comedores\Comedores_Totales\TEST\archivo.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "ID" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestion_de_Comedores\Comedores_Totales\TEST\archivo.php on line 6

Comment: Usa un `var_dump($_SERVER)` y publícalo para saber qué estás recibiendo, por favor.

Comment: eso es lo que me tira, lo único que cambie es la IP del server, por localhost.

Comment: Vale, encontré el problema, cambie los datos del archivo query.php y en el archivo JS, y en vez de que me muestre un valor true o false, lo cambie por 1 y 0.. y funciona perfecto.. no sé porque no me funciona con true o false, porque la columna es de tipo booleano